# How to dynamically create multiple nested objects in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Currently i'm doing website with newsletter posting. I want to post and show comments under every post.

MY POST

- first comment

  - comments to first comment

    - comments to second comment
      -so on...
- second comment
- third comment

I know how to dynamically create elements in a loop with one level of nesting. But how can i create multiple nesting?

For example I can create comments:

```
<div class='comments' th:each="comment : ${comments}">
  <div class='comment' th:text='comment'/>
</div>
```

How can I create multiple nesting?

```
<div class='comments' th:each="comment : ${comments}">
  <div class='comment' th:text='comment'>
      <div class='comment' here comment to comment/>
          etc..
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to do this with [fragments](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fragments).  For example, with an object like this:

Objects

```
class Comment {
    private String text;
    private List<Comment> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Comment(String text, Comment... children) {
        this.text = text;
        this.children.addAll(Arrays.asList(children));
    }

    public String getText() {return text;}
    public void setText(String text) {this.text = text;}

    public List<Comment> getChildren() {return children;}
    public void setChildren(List<Comment> children) {this.children = children;}
}
```

Controller:

```
List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
comments.add(new Comment("hello", new Comment("nooooo")));
comments.add(new Comment("it's another comment", new Comment("again", new Comment("yeah!"))));
comments.add(new Comment("whoopity doo"));
model.put("comments", comments);
```

You can output a chain of nested comments with fragments like this:

```
<th:block th:each="comment: ${comments}">
    <div th:replace="template :: comments(${comment})" />
</th:block>

<th:block th:if="${false}">
    <ul th:fragment="comments(comment)">
        <li>
            <div th:text="${comment.text}" />

            <th:block th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(comment.children)}" th:each="child: ${comment.children}">
                <div th:replace="template :: comments(${child})" />
            </th:block>
        </li>
    </ul>
</th:block>
```